# How to display a Swing timer's remaining time in one second intervals?

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener, countdown

I've been working on a simple game using a Java Applet in which the player's goal is to get as many points as possible within a 30 second timeframe. Right now, I'm using a Swing timer to count down from 30 seconds, and once the 0 mark is reached, a "game over" screen is displayed with the player's score. I have these instance variables:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        screenState = 0;
        repaint();
    }
};

Timer displayTimer = new Timer(30000, listener);
```

When the player clicks the "play" button, I execute `displayTimer.start();`.

Then, I have this within the appropriate case in my paint class:

```
g.drawString("Time Remaining: " + displayTimer.getDelay()/1000, 650, 100);
```

So, obviously, right now it's just displaying a static "Time Remaining: 30", and the screens switches after 30 seconds. What I'm trying to figure out is how I can repaint this value every one second so that it's a live timer. The only help I've been able to find thus far is for people use components.

Comment: you want to update your every 1 second?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Yes I would like to have the timer update every second so that it counts down in one second intervals.

Comment: I think you are completely misunderstanding the concept of how the javax.swing.Timer works. It is used as a _"ticker"_ and has no concept of time. The delay you are passing it is just the delay between "ticks". The code you put in the actionPerformed is what will accur every "delay" milliseconds. You're trying to draw the `delay()` which will always be the constant number you provided. You may want to make a global `count` variable that you use to draw, and decrease it in your actionPerformed, along with decreasing the delay to AndrewThompsons answer

Comment: @peeskillet That makes much more sense, thank you for the explanation. You're right, I was misunderstanding it completely. I'll see if I can fix that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

     int count = 0;

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (count++==30) {
            screenState = 0;
        }
        repaint();
    }
};

Timer displayTimer = new Timer(1000, listener); // make it 30 times faster
```

Comment: @user2901181 Andrew has set up a simple timer which ticks every second, he then uses a counter to determine how many times the timer has ticked,  when it gets to or exceeds 30 (30 seconds) he switches screen states. You can use this counter to determine how many seconds are left (30 - counter)

Comment: Thank you @AndrewThompson for the sample code and MadProgrammer for the help. I got it working now. Thanks for bearing with me...been at this all day and still kinda new to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the a `Thread` that sleep it every one second using the `sleep` method of it

Here is a little sample that count to 30 with 1 second interval

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int count = 0;
            while(true)
            {
                if(count == 30) //end at 30 second
                    break;

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println("updated");

                    ++count;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }); 
    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Not a good threading method for anything related to the Event Dispatch Thread (which includes Swing & AWT GUIs).

Comment: @AndrewThompson can always call the Event Dispatch in a Thread

Comment: Yes you can always do that, but given that adds extra LOC, it seems to be duck tape on top of a bad approach.  A GUI action (like `repaint()`) can be called directly from the `ActionListener` used in the `Timer`.